# populate IList<string> from long string

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have the following code

```
public IList<string> CensoredWords { get; private set; }

public Censor()
{
    this.CensoredWords = new List<string>
    {
        "word1",
        "word2",
        "word4"
    };
}
```

my web.config file contains the following

```
<add key="keywords" value="word1,word2,word3" />
```

obviously not very good especially if you want to add new words ect so ive modified it a bit to this

```
public Censor()
{
    this.CensoredWords = new List<string> { System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keywords"] };
}
```

ive also tried

```
public Censor()
{
    string[] keywords = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keywords"].Split(new char[] { ',' });
    foreach(string keyword in keywords)
    {
        this.CensoredWords.add(keyword);
    }
}
```

but for some reason nothing seems to be working, can anyone tell me why

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Side-note: instead of a `List<string>` i would use a [`HashSet<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) since it's more efficient if you need to look up a word.

Comment: How about an example of the string in the `Web.config`?

Comment: Why does it "not work"? What are the symptoms?

Comment: I thought after using the lastest version it was working but it doesnt throw any error it just seems to not populate the list

Comment: So what exactly is the contents of `System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keywords"]` (whitespace and all)?

Comment: Show us your web.config file.

Comment: Use the debugger to see that it actually gets anything from web.config. You can run `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keywords"]` in the immediate window to see that you get what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, looking at it you have the following:

```
public IList<string> CensoredWords { get; private set; }
```

Try setting it to not be private.

As an aside this code works:

```
string keywords = "Value1,Value2,Value3";
List<string> censoredWords = keywords.Split(',').ToList();
```

Comment: But it's in the constructor of this class, why should changing the property's setter to be non-private change anything?

Comment: It was my understanding (and I could well be wrong) that explicitly saying the setter was private prevents you from changing the value - effectively a read-only property.

Comment: now throws the Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error

Comment: sorted it thanks this.CensoredWords = keywords.Split(',').ToList();

Comment: @andrewslaughter: In your second approach you have forgotten to initialize the list: `this.CensoredWords=new List<string>();....`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reading the keys from the web.config file (thus presuming you don't want to edit the censored words from the application itself) you don't need the `set` property.

You could read the values in a static object so they are available from anywhere without re-parsing the list every time:

```
private static readonly List<string> _censoredWords  = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keywords"].Split(',').ToList();
public static IList<string> CensoredWords
{
    get
    {
         return _keywords;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix:

```
this.CensoredWords = new List<string>(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keywords"].Split(','));
```